# AWDS freeable memory and swap usage with high write low read usage

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, memory, rds

I am currently using a t2 micro mysql instance to store a data in AWS. I have a lambda function that is running every 2 minutes and inserting / updating a total of 3k rows. Data is being inserted and updated pretty frequently and the only time data is really being read (besides me running test queries from time to time) is once a day at 3AM where i am running 5 queries to generate 5 csv files based on the previous days data.

I can see my freeable memory dropping, and within the past day it has dropped below 100mb and swap usage has gone up from about 5mb to 15mb. I've read some other SO threads about freeable memory, but none of them have really answered the question I have. My question is how important is freeable memory if I am primarily doing writes to the DB. I am planning on upgrading to the next tier soon, but I'd like to know how important this is and if I should consider making sure that the freeable memory is always above a certain threshold. My DBA experience is slim to none so I'm don't have too much knowledge about what is going on under the hood and if it is stuff i need to worry about

Comment: Have you experienced any performance issues?

Comment: Nope, performance has been pretty consistent

Comment: So why worry? Memory is to be used. If you'd reset the instance it would probably go back to being high.